# How to fetch ngPrime autocomplete text on button click in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete

I am using `ngPrime` autocomplete to fetch data from service. My requirement is to fetch text written in autocomplete at any instance on button click. I tried to fetch value using getElementById.value in the component but it is returning `undefined`.

```
  <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="contact" [suggestions]="contactList.TaxEntities" (completeMethod)="filterContact($event)"
        field="TaxEntityName" [size]="30" placeholder="Search Contact" [minLength]="1" appendTo="body" id="auto">
        <ng-template let-selectedItem pTemplate="item">
            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                {{selectedItem.TaxEntityName}}, {{selectedItem.TaxEntityABN}}
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: can you please create or put minimal code, i want to know why you are using getElementbyid to fetch selected item? or look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete it will help you

Comment: Actually, I have created a reusable component i.e Autocomplete. I am using this component in another component. In another component, there is a button that required autocomplete text value at any instance. Hence, I tried to fetch autocomplete value by its id. But, it is not giving value

Comment: This is the code in another component.html file                                                 
  <app-data>Resuable autocompletelte component</app-data>                                            <button (click)="filter(autocomplete value)">Search Contact</button>
Here, I want to fetch autocomplete value. How I can achieve it?

Comment: I am not sure, you need to take value by using [(ngModel)]="brand" from your reusableComponent and pass that value to another component filter data in another component and return filtered data to youe reusableComponent this all things you can achive by using `@input and @output`, I am not sure about what is your code in reusablecomponent and anothercomponent.

Comment: you want me to create some sample for you than you have to put some code of your  reusablecomponent and another component with html and array which will you use for filter data thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

- This is the code in another component.html file Resuable autocompletelte component Search Contact Here, I want to fetch autocomplete value. How I can achieve it?

> You needs to handle this by  using [input and output detectors](https://blog.hackages.io/angular-component-interaction-with-input-output-and-eventemitter-72526422b95c). You can pass the values to child component from parent component by using input decorator. you can use output(event emitter)  to get the child component values in parent component